# How different is Deferred Exection in IEnumerable and IQueryeable

Tags: linq

Please help me to understand the concept clearly.

I have a IEnumberable list of employees,

Eg :

```
var emplist = new List<Employee> ()
{ 
    new Employee { EmpID = 1, EmpName = 'emp1', Age = 21}, 
    new Employee { EmpID = 2, EmpName = 'emp2', Age = 26},
    new Employee { EmpID = 3, EmpName = 'emp3',Age = 28} 
};
```

**IEnumerable**

```
var lst = from emp in emplist 
          where emp.Age > 25 
          select emp; 
// Returns IEnumerable and subjected to deferred execution.

var singleemp = lst.Take(1); // for filtering first employee.
```

**IQueryeable**

```
IQueryeable<Employee> lst = from emp in emplist  
                            where emp.Age > 25 
                            select emp;   
// Returns IQuereable and subjected to deferred execution.

var singleemp = lst.Take(1); // for filtering first employee.
```

Now here i have two scenarios for IEnumerable and IQuereable but the Sql query generated in DB is different. But both are subjected to deferred execution. So how this two scenarios makes difference!

Can please somebody give a hint on this ...

Comment: The SQL in both cases should be the same, I would think. `IQueryable` inherits `IEnumerable`, so both *should* be enumerated in the same way.

Comment: @cdhowie : thats where i got confused. If we are going with Iqueryeable then in the query itself it put TOP(1) since we have Take (1) ahead. But in Ienumereable its getting all details of the employee and filter it in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have to have a variable typed `IQueryable<T>` in order for the `.Take(1)` operation to be made known to the query engine in use (SQL in this case).  If you apply this to an `IEnumerable<T>` then the operation is performed only in C#, after the query has been executed on the server.  You need to have an `IQueryable<T>`-typed variable in order to apply extra query instructions to be executed on the server.

If you use `var` as the type when assigning the query to a variable, then the variable should be typed as specifically as possible, and this should be `IQueryable<T>` or a type implementing this interface if the object you are querying is also a queryable.

In your example code you are operating on a `List<T>`, so the results of using a queryable or an enumerable will be exactly the same.  If you are operating on a queryable type, however, you will see a difference.

Comment: cdhowie, this gets confusing so much says to use IQueryable for deferred execution and the "prebuilding" of things for the db engine.  Yet, supposedly IEnumerable does deferred execution also.  "A query that returns IEnumerable still supports deferred execution, but at least some larger portion of the result is likely to have been generated than is the case with LINQ to SQL. In other words, all types of LINQ support deferred execution, but LINQ to SQL supports it more fully than LINQ to Objects or LINQ to XML."https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charlie/2007/12/10/linq-and-deferred-execution/